# Strange kind of null in Oracle: "is not null" does not match it but nvl does

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a view that represents an organisation chart. At the top of the chart the parent node is empty and the corresponding field is null, but also not null (?)

This finds nothing:

```
select *
  from the_weird_view t
 where t.parent_nsq is null
```

But this works:

```
select *
  from the_weird_view t
 where nvl(t.parent_nsq, -666) = -666
```

It appears to be caused by a combination of a recursive query and non-ansi joins.

This works normally:

```
with
 ANSI
  as
   (select c.code     as child_code,
           p.code     as parent_code,
           p.code_nsq as parent_nsq
      from links  l
      join codes  c  on (c.code_nsq = l.child_code_nsq)
 left join codes  p  on (p.code_nsq = l.parent_code_nsq)
  connect by child_code_nsq = prior parent_code_nsq
  start with parent_code_nsq is null)         
--
select * from ANSI where parent_nsq is null
```

This behaves oddly:

```
 WTF
  as
   (select c.code     as child_code,
           p.code     as parent_code,
           p.code_nsq as parent_nsq
      from links  l
          , codes  c
          , codes  p
     where     c.code_nsq    = l.child_code_nsq
           and p.code_nsq(+) = l.parent_code_nsq
  connect by child_code_nsq = prior parent_code_nsq
  start with parent_code_nsq is null)         
--
-- select * from WTF where parent_code is null     -- Works normally
-- select * from WTF where nvl(parent_nsq, 0) = 0  -- Works
select * from WTF where parent_nsq is null      -- Returns nothing?!
```

My question, apart from "what the?!", is whether this is a bug and what if anything to do about it (apart from updating *the_weird_view* of course)?

Edit: so it sounds like a plain old bug. We're on version 11g 64bit (11.2.0.4.0).

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bug; which exact version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Possibly bug 7375615, if you're between 10.2.0.4 or 11gR1? Or could be others with similar symptoms.